# Web loading/stress with Torture. Working in Windows?

Tags: perl, iis

I found this fanstastic perl script for testing the stability of the web serves (http://stein.cshl.org/~lstein/torture). I´m currently using it with my webpage and my server, which runs in IIS (Miscrosoft).

I´m running it in Windows, using strawberry (Perl).

This is a naive question: in the page it says that works with UNIX. But if the forks (for testing concurrency) are made in windows (using strawberry), the script will work in the IIS server? This is: the information would be sent from my PC to the IIS server. The server would not need to be running in UNIX: is this right?

I tested on google, yahoo, but maybe there are running in UNIX, and that´s why it works.

If tested in Microsoft.com without forks, just plain: no concurrency, I get:

```
Transactions 1
Elapsed Time 213.66 sec  A LOT!!!!
Bytes Tranferred: 1020 bytes
Response Time: 213.17 sec
Transaction Rate: 0.00 trans/sec NOTHING???
Concurrency: 1.0
...
```

Why this results? Is this becuase is not running in UNIX? -guessing that MS run their servers in IIS, or smething like that-. If I tried to Fork, it takes FOREVER.

When testing in my website, the results are WORST.

What could be the reason?

Comment: It seems like you need to run the script on *NIX rather than Windows.

Comment: Well, I´m running it in Windows, using strawberry PERL, and it seems to work. But not sure, about the resutls

Comment: I'm guessing that you running on Windows leads to your results. If you've got access to a Linux box, try running it there and see if you get the same results. I doubt it would fail to stress test IIS.

Comment: "It uses the fork() call ... Unfortunately this means that the script will only run on Unix ports of Perl." may have been true back in 1999, but that's certainly not the case today. That said, there are gotchas with fork in Windows. You can't install a SIGCHLD handler in Windows, so you need to call `waitpid -1,&WNOHANG` frequently to reap the child processes. The limits on the number of simultaneous child processes you can have also tends to be lower (as low as 64) on Windows than on other platforms.

Comment: Thank you. I tried in a MAC, which uses UNIX. And the results are slow. The script ends, but REALLY slow. The statistics are not that good, the transactions are nearly zero. MAybe the script is outdated for teh actual technology?
Do you know an alternative for this? Maybe a free stress tester? With many concurrent users -thousands-